# How to update a flag in existing running Spring Boot Application without restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, runtime

I have a spring boot application running a feature. I want to toggle that feature(on/off) at runtime without redeploying or restarting the application. Issue is that I can't deploy any rest endpoint as server has only exposed some specific port because of security.

I want to remotely control the toggle so that I can set that feature on and off. I tried reading the environment variable on my local machine using:

```
System.getEnv("envVariable")
```

but even after updating it using `export envVariable=true` it's not reflecting updated value in the code.

Can someone suggest any way to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide the code where this env variable is being read. If that is at bean level, and beans are singleton, then you must need to restart the application to re-initialize the beans to read the updated value. To get the updated value every time, you need to read this value at method level.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need some more dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

in properties file you need to write

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

and on the class wherever you are are using environment variables use Annotation **@RefreshScope** like

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class DemoController {   
    @Value("${my.data}")
    String str;
    // code
}
```

and whenever you are changing environment variable just hit a post request **http://localhost:PORT/actuator/refresh**

using above configuration you can change the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is a programming pattern **Feature Toggle** that provides a way to turn on/off application components during the runtime. The core idea is to ask property files or database config table about current states of config fields and change application functionality if config changed. This pattern described here https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html. You can find more by using keyword "Feature Flags".

One of popular implementations of Feature Flags for Java is **togglz** (https://www.togglz.org/quickstart.html).

Here is an exaple of using togglz:

1. Create enum for features representation

   ```
    public enum MyFeatures implements Feature {

    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("First Feature")
    FEATURE_ONE,

    @Label("Second Feature")
    FEATURE_TWO;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
    }
   ```
2. Implement TogglzConfig

   ```
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class DemoConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {

    public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
        return MyFeatures.class;
    }

    public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
        return new FileBasedStateRepository(new File("/tmp/features.properties"));
    }

    public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
        return new ServletUserProvider("admin");
    }
   ```

   }
3. Describe the feature behavior depended on toggle:

   ```
   if( MyFeatures.FEATURE_ONE.isActive() ) {
   ```

   // new stuff here
   }

Source: https://www.togglz.org/quickstart.html